# How to calculate between different group of rows of the same table

Tags: sql

Having a table as:

```
Year   Month   Value
2011   1       500
2011   2       550
2011   3       600
...
...
2012   1       600
2012   2       750
2012   3       930
```

Is there a way I can calculate the difference between values of same month/different years, so to get a result as:

```
Month    Value
1        100
2        200
3        330
...
```

I tried to do something like:

```
select month, a.value-b.value
from
  (select month, value from table where year = 2012) a,
  (select month, value from table where year = 2011) b
```

but the output is 12 months (of select a (2012) * 12 month of select b (2011)..

---

edit: sorry for the lack of important information:

The queries are being made to a excel sheet via odbc:jdbc bridge.

as the "from" clause is always like this: [sheet1$] i'm not being able to create any joins or case :(

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't work because you're doing a `CROSS JOIN` (because of `,`) on the tables, so each row is matched with every row in the other table, rather than an `INNER JOIN` on the month.

**Modifying your query:**

```
select a.month, a.value-b.value
from
  (select month, value from table where year = 2012) a
  JOIN
  (select month, value from table where year = 2011) b
  ON a.month = b.month
```

**A faster query:**

```
select a.month, a.value-b.value
from
  yourTable a
  join yourTable b
    on a.month = b.month
  where a.year = 2012 and b.year = 2011
```

**For multiple rows per month for each year:**

```
select a.month, a.value-b.value
from
  (select month, sum(value) as value
   from yourTable where year = 2012
   group by month) a
  join
  (select month, sum(value) as value
   from yourTable where year = 2011
   group by month) b
    on a.month = b.month
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9a97/7).

Answer (score 3):

You were very close to how to get the result.  I would suggest using something similar to this which *pivots* the data into columns and then you can take the difference between each year:

```
select month,
  Year2012-Year2011 as Diff
from
(
  select month,
    sum(case when year = 2011 then value end) Year2011,
    sum(case when year = 2012 then value end) Year2012
  from yourtable
  group by month
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16737/3)

Comment: what happens when he has year 2013, 2014 and so on. Can we have generalised query?

Comment: @AshReva You could create a dynamic query to generate the list of years but the OP would have to state what RDBMS they are using because the syntax would be different for each one.

Comment: @AshReva there are many different ways to perform this query.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Assuming `year`/`month` is unique.

```
SELECT
    a.month,
    a.value - b.value
FROM
    tablename a
    INNER JOIN tablename b
        ON a.year - 1 = b.year
        AND a.month = b.month
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `where` clause to your query..

```
select month, a.value-b.value
from
  (select month, value from table where year = 2012) a,
  (select month, value from table where year = 2011) b
where a.month = b.month
```

What you are doing is cross join, makes combination of each row from first table with each row of second column where will filter out rows which have been matched with different month number.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a self join.  The general idea is to select from the same table twice, but with different aliases.

```
select t1.something, t2.something
from yourtable t1 join yourtable t2 on something
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

select a.month,(a.value-(select b.value from @tablename b where b.year = @year2 and b.month = a.month)) as diff 
from @tablename a
where a.year = @year1

I think it will help you. Actually as we know that we can use only two numbers in substraction so that here i'have used the year1 and year 2. Put your table name at the proper place

Answer (score 0):

In addition if there are only 2 values per month as in your example and analytic functions are available in your version of SQL then this will work. You may partition it differently...:

```
SELECT distinct month, (l_val - f_val) value
  FROM
  (
  SELECT year, month, month_val
       , FIRST_VALUE(month_val) OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY month) f_val 
      , LAST_VALUE(month_val) OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY month) l_val 
    FROM your_table
  )
 ORDER BY 1
 /

MONTH    VALUE
----------------
1        100
2        200
3        330
```

In my personal opinion inline view is better to use then join, although you will join anyway but it is still more readable ad easier to debug...