# Add variance in the rows of table

Tags: reporting-services

I've a SSRS report which should look like below,

```
--------------------------------
Year Product Total customers
--------------------------------
2015 prd1      100
     prd2       50
     prd3       60

2014 prd1       80
     prd2       60
     prd3       60

Varience
    Prd1        20
    Prd2       -10
    Prd3         0
```

I've done the year wise grouping and the data mapping. But I'm not sure how to add variance(between 2015-2014) in each row based on the each product of the year

### Update:

My dataset looks like this

```
Year    CategoryId  CategoryDesc    TotalCustomerCount  
2013    Prd1        Testproduct     100
2013    Prd2        Testprod2       50
2013    Prd3        Tesrprod3       45
2014    Prd1        Testproduct     80
2014    Prd2        Testprod2       60
```

You can see that some products may miss out in a year.

**Note**: The dataset is created from a Dimesional cube and not from SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to handle this requeriment is generating the data from the query using T-SQL. However the output you require can be produced from SSRS using a dataset with the same structure as the dataset you provided in the update.

In order to recreate your scenario I used this dataset.

```
Year    Product     CategoryDesc    TotalCustomerCount  
2013    Prd1        Testproduct     100
2013    Prd2        Testprod2       50
2013    Prd3        Tesrprod3       45
2014    Prd1        Testproduct     80
2014    Prd2        Testprod2       60
```

My approach is take the minimum and maximum year values (2013 and 2014)  and the product in every row and look up the TotalCustomerCount to substract it. This is a step by step guide.

First, create a calculated field in your dataset. Right click the dataset in Report Data pane, call it `Year_Product` and set this expression in the field source textbox.

```
=Fields!Year.Value & "-" & Fields!Product.Value
```

This will produce an additional field called `Year_Product` which has `Year` and `Product` fields concatenated with the `-` character in middle. In example: `2013-Prd1`, `2014-Prd1`, `2013-Prd3` etc.

Now create a tablix with this data arrangement:

[image]

In the cell highlighted in red use this expression:

```
=Lookup(Max(Fields!Year.Value,"DataSet13") & "-" &
Fields!Product.Value,Fields!Year_Product.Value,Fields!TotalCustomerCount.Value,"DataSet13")
-
Lookup(Min(Fields!Year.Value,"DataSet13") & "-" &
Fields!Product.Value,Fields!Year_Product.Value,Fields!TotalCustomerCount.Value,"DataSet13")
```

This will look up the max year and product of the row in the `Year_Product` field and get the TotalCustomerCount.

`Year_Product`: 2014-Prd1 and `TotalCustomerCount`: 80

`Year_Product`: 2013-Prd1 and `TotalCustomerCount` 100

The above example produces `-20` since `80 - 100 = -20`

It will show us repeated products because every product may be present two times. To avoid this it is necessary to sort the tablix by Product, go to tablix properties and set the below sorting option.

[image]

Now hide duplicated rows. Go to tablix properties / Row visibility and select Show or hide based on an expression.

[image]

Use this expression ton conditionally hide the duplicated products:

```
=IIF(
Fields!Product.Value=PREVIOUS(Fields!Product.Value),
true,
false
)
```

Finally if you preview the report you will see something like this (I recreated your both tables.)

[image]

> Note I am using only one dataset, the same that you provide in your
>   question.

Hopefully this what you are looking for let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, It was perfect. I've another problem, see if you can help me on that too. Consider the same report I mentioned earlier, and if I have a column which has an expression to show of the value ( this has even lookup with other dataset). How do I calculate the variance for these columns which has an expression already having a lookup?? Nested lookup is not allowed in SSRS right?

Comment: With that very short description I cannot help you, you have to post another question or edit your current question but I think the issue in this question has been solved at least for the initial problem you posted

Comment: @alesandro Yes, my initial problem is resolved.I'll try to create a new question on that.

Comment: Oops,, I awarded the bounty wrongly to the other answer. Is there any way to award one more bounty ??

Comment: No idea man... Never used bounty system. Flag the question for moderation and contact an moderator.

Answer (score 2):

It is kind of hard to tell exactly without knowing what your current dataset looks like.

But I believe that Stanislovas' example will be of little use to you because his example only works if your dataset has a single row for each product, with columns with the total for each year. Which I'm guessing you do not have because you used row grouping to get the above result. If you did, you could've used column-grouping instead of row-grouping to get a better overview.

You have two possibilities:

1. Replace your current dataset completely with a dataset that has columns for each year value (like in Stanislovas' example). To achieve this kind of dataset you need your query to look like this for example:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT(myTable.Product), t1.Total AS 'Total2014', t2.Total AS 'Total2015'
   FROM myTable 
   JOIN (SELECT Product, SUM(Total) AS Total
      FROM myTable
      WHERE Year = 2014
      GROUP BY Product) as t1 ON t1.Product = myTable.Product
   JOIN (SELECT Product, SUM(Total) AS Total
      FROM myTable
      WHERE Year = 2015
      GROUP BY Product) as t2 ON t2.Product = myTabel.Product
   ```

   This can then be used to make a table that looks like this:

   ```
   ---------------------------------------
   | Product  | 2014  | 2015  | Variance |
   ---------------------------------------
   | prd1     | 100   | 80    | 20       | 
   | prd2     | 50    | 60    | -10      | 
   | prd3     | 60    | 60    | 0        | 
    ...
   ```
2. Or you can add a second datasource that has calculated these differences before sending it to the reporter. Here is an example to help you with your query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15002915/4579864

If you need any more help, just leave a comment and I'll try and explain furthur. This should at least get you started.

Comment: I forgot to mention an important information. I'm using SSAS to create dimensional cube which becomes a data source for my datasets. My dataset is like having rows for each year and each product. In this case how do I calculate the variance?? Is there any option using calculated fields?

Comment: You can only calculate a variance between 2 entities. If you have 3 years for example, how are you supposed to calculate the variance?

Comment: I'll have only two years, it will be a parameter selection