# TSQL - left join different rows of a table uniquely

Tags: t-sql

I am recording the connection and disconnection time of a device in a table.

The final purpose is to define the maximum disconnection time.

My table looks like this

[image: my table data]

Before proceeding with the maximum DATEDIFF calculation I tried to attempt a DATEDIFF between each disconnection-connection rows (see the picture below):

[image: Testing the DATEDIFF]

The query is obviously wrong because it is making a difference between all of the "Disconnected" and "Connected" rows.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: why such a complex logic. I think it can be done quite simply. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15002915/7549867

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I am struggling to obtain only rows 1 and 3.

I was then thinking to reorder the table by descending order and select the top 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Note that negative value implies that the connection is still active

```
;WITH cte_Connectivity(DeviseID, EventTime, EventType) AS
(
SELECT 1,'2017-3-24 00:01:00.000', 'On' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'2017-3-24 00:02:00.000', 'Off' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2017-3-24 00:01:00.000', 'On' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2017-3-24 00:04:00.000', 'Off' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'2017-3-24 00:01:00.000', 'On' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'2017-3-24 00:01:00.000', 'On' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'2017-3-24 00:06:00.000', 'Off' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'2017-3-24 00:01:00.000', 'On' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'2017-3-24 00:10:00.000', 'Off'
)
SELECT a.DeviseID,
    a.EventTime,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.EventTime, ISNULL(b.EventTime, DATEADD(minute, - 1, a.EventTime))) AS TimeConnected
FROM cte_Connectivity a
LEFT JOIN cte_Connectivity b
    ON CASE 
            WHEN a.EventType = 'On'
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END = CASE 
            WHEN b.EventType = 'Off'
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END
        AND a.DeviseID = b.DeviseID
WHERE a.EventType = 'ON'
```

Answer (score 0):

I then easily solved the problem:

1. created two views (one with only on, starting from the thrid row, and the other with only off rows)
2. joined both tables and added another column with a DATEDIFF
3. then create a new view that looks for the maximum datediff

... nothing special, thank you again folks!