# How to calculate the difference in revenue for 2 specific periods from data in a single table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query which is supposed to calculate the difference in total revenue based on 2 specific periods. The data to perform the computation come from a single SQL Table.

To summarize, I have a column in table `T1` called `Revenue` and another column called `Month`. I need to find the difference in revenue for Months September 2020 to December 2020 versus September 2019 to December 2019.

My T-SQL query stands as follows:

```sql
USE [MyDatabase]

;with cte1 as 
(
  SELECT 
    sum ([Revenue]) as 'Revenue Sep 19 - Dec 19'
  FROM
    [T1]
  WHERE
    [Month] between '2019-09-01' and '2019-12-01'
),
cte2 as (
  SELECT
    sum ([Revenue]) as 'Revenue Sep 20 - Dec 20'
  FROM
    [T1]
  WHERE
    [Month] between '2020-09-01' and '2020-12-01'
),
cte3 as (
  SELECT 
    cte2.[Revenue Sep 20 - Dec 20] as 'Total Revenue',
    'Sep 20 - Dec 20' as 'Period',
    '1' as 'ID'
  FROM
    [cte2]

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT 
    cte1.[Revenue Sep 19 - Dec 19] as 'Total Revenue',
    'Sep 19 - Dec 19' as 'Period',
    '1' as 'ID'
  FROM
    [cte1]
)
select a.[Total Revenue] - b.[Total Revenue]
from
  (select cte3.[Total Revenue] from [cte3] where cte3.[Period] = 'Sep 20 - Dec 20') a
  JOIN
  (select cte3.[Total Revenue] from [cte3] where cte3.[Period] = 'Sep 19 - Dec 19') b
  ON b.[ID] = a.[ID]
```

I have based my query on the following: [How to calculate between different group of rows of the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002798/how-to-calculate-between-different-group-of-rows-of-the-same-table)

However, when running my query, I am getting the following error message:

> Invalid column name 'ID'.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. Isn't column `ID` present in the `cte3`?

Comment: `Isn't column ID present in the cte3?` - it is, but it's not selected in either `a` or `b`.

Comment: oh silly me! You are right. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ID` must be present in the select list of both `a` and `b` for it to be visible to the `join`:

```sql
from
  (select cte3.ID, cte3.[Total Revenue] from [cte3] where cte3.[Period] = 'Sep 20 - Dec 20') a
  JOIN
  (select cte3.ID, cte3.[Total Revenue] from [cte3] where cte3.[Period] = 'Sep 19 - Dec 19') b
  ON b.[ID] = a.[ID]
```

Answer (score 2):

You query is way more complicated than necessary.

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] between '2020-09-01' and '2020-12-01' THEN [Revenue] ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] between '2019-09-01' and '2019-12-01' THEN [Revenue] ELSE 0 END)
       ) as difference
FROM [T1];
```

Your version has three CTEs, a `UNION ALL`, two subqueries, and a `JOIN`.

Notes:

- Do not use single quotes to delimit column aliases.  Only use single quotes for strings and dates.
- Name your column aliases so they don't need to be escaped.  For instance, use underscores instead of spaces.
- Do not use meaningless table aliases such as `a` and `b`.  Use meaningful ones, such as `t2019`.

Answer (score 1):

While using `SUB QUERY` you must mention the Column which you mention in the **Join** condition also

```
SELECT A.[TOTAL REVENUE] - B.[TOTAL REVENUE]
FROM
(SELECT CTE3.[TOTAL REVENUE],CTE3.ID FROM [CTE3] WHERE CTE3.[PERIOD] = 'SEP 20 - DEC 20') A
JOIN
(SELECT CTE3.[TOTAL REVENUE],CTE3.ID FROM [CTE3] WHERE CTE3.[PERIOD] = 'SEP 19 - DEC 19') B ON B.[ID] = A.[ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code, It will help you

```
USE [MyDatabase]

select sum([Revenue Sep 20 - Dec 20])-sum([Revenue Sep 19 - Dec 19]) as revenue_diffrence 
from
(
SELECT 
    [Revenue] as 'Revenue Sep 19 - Dec 19', 0 as 'Revenue Sep 20 - Dec 20'
  FROM
    [T1]
  WHERE
    [Month] between '2019-09-01' and '2019-12-01'

union all
SELECT
    0 as 'Revenue Sep 19 - Dec 19',[Revenue] as 'Revenue Sep 20 - Dec 20'
  FROM
    [T1]
  WHERE
    [Month] between '2020-09-01' and '2020-12-01'
)a
```